# Rails 4/Bootstrap 3: removing has-error wrappers from simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 and Rails 4 and I am trying to get rid of all the pesky "has-error" wrappers around my fields in a simple-form.

I have added

```
  config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance|
  html_tag
   }
```

to my config/application.rb

but nothing is happening. There are many posts on this but none of the solutions seem to work. I am restarting my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in **config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb** 
(Notice the "error_class" option is now a blank string everywhere, and also the b.use :error option has been removed)

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.error_notification_class = 'alert alert-danger'
  config.button_class = "btn btn-primary pull-right"
  config.boolean_label_class = nil

  config.wrappers :vertical_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'

    b.use :input, class: 'form-control'

    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :vertical_file_input, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'

    b.use :input

    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :vertical_boolean, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'checkbox' do |ba|
      ba.use :label_input
    end


    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'
    b.use :input

    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-control'

      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal_form_medium, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-5' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-control'

      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end  

  config.wrappers :horizontal_file_input, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input

      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal_boolean, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9' do |wr|
      wr.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'checkbox' do |ba|
        ba.use :label_input, class: 'col-sm-9'
      end

      wr.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input

      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :inline_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: '' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'sr-only'

    b.use :input, class: 'form-control'

    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  # Wrappers for forms and inputs using the Bootstrap toolkit.
  # Check the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com)
  # to learn about the different styles for forms and inputs,
  # buttons and other elements.
  config.default_wrapper = :vertical_form
  config.wrapper_mappings = {
    check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :vertical_file_input,
    boolean: :vertical_boolean,
  }
end
```

To bring back the error wrapper, put the following back into each wrapper block:

```
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
```

to change the error wrapper class, change the class name in this key value pair:

```
error_class: 'has-error'
```